# How to get proper hostname instead of NETBIOS name

Tags: spacemacs, microsoft-windows, system-environment

I'm using emacs 25.2.1 on Windows with spacemacs (0.200.9). I also start emacs as a service using `emacsclientw.exe --daemon`. I'm attempting to get the current host name using `(system-name)` as follows:

```
(defconst jp-hostname
  (car (split-string (system-name) "\\." t)))
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, the `jp-hostname` variable contains the NETBIOS name instead of the hostname. For example, my laptop's name is "jaundiced-outlook", but `jp-hostname` is set to "JAUNDICED-OUTLO".

Calling `(system-name)` after emacs is up and running returns what I would expect: "jaundiced-outlook".

By waiting until emacs is finished loading and executing the above code using `eval-region`, `jp-hostname` gets set correctly to "jaundiced-outlook".

Is there a reason for this behavior? Is there a way to get around this kind of thing?

Comment: How are you evaluating that using Emacs in the case where it returns the wrong value, if you are not doing that "*after emacs is started*"? It's not clear (to me) just what you are doing. You might want to provide a recipe, starting with no init file.

Comment: When I start emacs using -q, (message (system-name)) displays the NETBIOS name in the messages buffer. The "after emacs is started" would occur if I select the code in question and run eval-region. I'll clean up the question appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, the only reliable way I found to resolve the issue (how do I get the host name, not the NETBIOS name) was to shell out to the `hostname` command:

```
(defconst jp-hostname
  ;; This should use the following line, but it doesn't work for some reason
  ;; So, instead, we resort to shelling out
  ;; (car (split-string (system-name) "\\." t))
  (string-trim (with-output-to-string
    (call-process "hostname" nil standard-output nil))))
```